# (KDB+/q) Get diagonal elements of a matrix

Tags: kdb

I want to get all the diagonal elements of a matrix in kdb+/q.

E.g.

```
q)A:(1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9)
q)A
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

would return `1 5 9`

My idea is to use "." to get the elements.

```
q) A . 1 1 / one of the diagonal elements
5
q) 2 #' til 3 / indices
0 0
1 1
2 2
```

But I tried many ways and can't get it working.

Answer (score 3):

Following code returns diagonal elements of matrix

```
(1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9) @' til 3
```

The code

1. generates continuous list `0, 1, 2` on the right
2. Gets an element from every list on the left by applying corresponding index on the right (`@'` adverb)

Generic form looks like:

```
getDiagonal: {x@'til count x};
getDiagonal (1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9)
```